# Conditional operator inside anonymous object

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
var x = new {
    Name = "qwe",
    Options = someList.Select(x=>x.KEY).Select(x => 
        new {

            Title: someOtherList.FirstOrDefault(y => y.KEY == x) != null ? 
                   someOtherList.FirstOrDefault(y => y.KEY == x).Title : 
                   null
        }
    )
}).ToList();
```

I'm making a serializeable list of objects. Please have a look on how i fetch the `Title` property for each option.

My problem is that I'm fetching more properties than the title, and the conditional operator feels quite excessive for each property.

Is there any "better" way of writing this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to perform a [left outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)?

Comment: It's called the [Conditional Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx). Ternary operator refers to any operator which accepts 3 operands.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ok, because the first result gives me `?:`: https://www.google.se/search?q=c%23+ternary+operator&oq=c%23+ternary+operator&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j60j62l3.2816j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Johan: There currently is only one ternary operator in C# and most other languages. And that's why a lot of people use those two terms synonymously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the following:

```
Title= someOtherList.Where(y => y.KEY == x).Select(x => x.Title).FirstOrDefault()
```

That is doing the following:

1. From someOtherList, return those elements with `Key` equal to `x`.
2. From those elements, select the `Title`.
3. Return the first title - or `null` if there are none.

Comment: What will happen when `y => y.KEY == x` returns null?

Comment: @johan it wont, youre selecting off the other list first

Comment: @Johan: A comparison never returns `null`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Let me rephrase it: What will happens when `where()` returns zero results? The reasons that I used `?:` in the first place was to handle nulls returned from `firstOrDefault()`. The eqvavivalent here would be an empty result from `where()`

Comment: oh i take it back this does make sense and will return nulls correctly, very nice :)

Comment: @Johan: If `Where` returns zero results, the result of the complete query is `null`, just as in your original code.

Comment: Yes, but what will happen when you run your `Select()` on that? Woulnd't that throw an exception?

Comment: @Johan: No. The `Select` expression is executed for every element in the result set. Since there are no elements, it won't be executed.

Comment: Since the relation is 1:1, I don't see the need for `Where()` here. Why not `someOtherList.FirstOrDefault(y=>y.Key == x).Select(x => x != null ? x.Title : null)` ?

Comment: @Johan: That wouldn't compile. `FirstOrDefault` returns a single element of whatever type the elements in `someOtherList` are. Unless it implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can't `Select` on it. And even if it would implement `IEnumerable<T>` the `Select` would be on the elements inside your result, i.e. it would mean something different.

Comment: @Johan: I added a textual description to my answer to explain what happens. Maybe that makes it clearer.

Comment: Yes, I understand what it does. But since there will be either 0 or 1 match, I thought that `FirstOrDefault` could be used instead of `Where`. But I guess that's not possible. Thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Canonically, the approach most similar to the original code is to use a [statement lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).

```
Options = someList.Select(x=>x.KEY).Select(x => 
    {
        var other = someOtherList.FirstOrDefault(y => y.KEY == x);
        return new {
           Title = other == null ? null : other.Title
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method instead:

```
Options = someList.Select(x=>x.KEY).Select(x => CreateObject(x, someOtherList));

public YourObject(or dynamic) CreateObject(YourObject x, List<SomeOtherObject> someOtherList)
{
    var other = someOtherList.FirstOrDefault(y => y.KEY == x);

    return new
    {
        Title = (other == null ? null : other.Title),
        Foo = (other == null ? null : other.Foo),
        ...
    }
}
```

Or accomplish the same with the `let` keyword in a [Linq query expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx) as @DarinDimitrov displays.